# I got a different answer from the instructor's solution on the limit.Can someone verify my answer?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

So, I did a limit and it gave me infinity but the answer from the teacher says DNE.Also graphing it on desmos, I felt like it went to infinity, but I'm not sure.
Can anyone help? I'm not allowed to use hospital rule to solve it though I don't know if its possible to use it.Anyways, This is what I did, please help [equation and my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6gVa.png)

Comment: When a function grows arbitrarily large, that is, tends to $\infty$, one doesn't normally say that the limit exists and equals $\infty$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Important to remember that $\infty$ is not a number but is instead a symbol for unbounded growth.  That is why, if the expression grows unbounded, the limit will often be referred to as *not existing*.

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter has said, a limit doesn't "exist" if it goes to infinity. So saying both infinity and DNE are correct.